# Trying to get property of non-object on running laravel queue work command

Tags: laravel, serialization, laravel-artisan

I am getting a really weird issue with my laravel 5.1 app. When I run the command

```
$ php artisan queue:work
```

I get the error below:

```
  [ErrorException]                                                             
  Trying to get property of non-object (View: /var/www/html/divostar/resource  
  s/views/emails/password_update.blade.php)                                    



  [ErrorException]                      
  Trying to get property of non-object
```

Below is how I send the email

```
 $user = $this->user->get_user_by_id($id);
 Mail::queue('emails.password_update', ['user' => $user, 'password' => $password], function($message) use ($user){
            $message->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject('Account Password Updated');
            $message->replyTo(config('mail.replyTo.address'), config('mail.replyTo.name'));
            $message->priority(1);
        });
```

This is weird because this same code is working well on another server. I have done the following on this server but with no success:

```
$ composer dump-autoload
$ php artisan clear-compiled
$ php artisan cache:clear
$ sudo apachectl restart
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Check `$user` variable is set or not. just make it `dd($user)` . I think you're doing wrong in `$user = $this->user->get_user_by_id($id)`  this line

Comment: The variable is set. See message in jobs table `| 1052 | userqueue | {"job":"mailer@handleQueuedMessage","data":{"view":"emails.password_update","data":{"user":{"id":7,"name":"Daniel"`

Comment: In addition this code is working on another server

Comment: @FokwaBest, This happens when you try to access variable which doesn't exist as pointed out by @sumon, If you are getting this on jobs table then you are not referring the right user. Post the `dd($user)` result.

Comment: Hi @NaumanZafar. I am getting the right user. I think this is more of a serialization issue as this same code is working on another server. anyway here is my dd `'User {#458 #table: "users" #hidden: array:2  #connection: null  #primaryKey: "id" #perPage: 15 +incrementing: true+timestamps: true #attributes: array:24 [ "id" => 7 "name" => "Daniel"'`

Comment: @FokwaBest Share your view code.

Comment: ` Hello {{ $user->name }},<br/><br/>`

Comment: Try doing a `dd(serialize($user));` to check whether the user is serializable (as I understand if you're going to queue something it needs to be serialized in order to be added to a queue).

Comment: You're passing the whole user object to the view, try replacing that with only the values you need in the view. Like @apokryfos said. This might be an object serialization issue with queue.

Comment: Hi @Sandeesh. If that is really the issue, why would this same code work on another server? I am testing it right now and is working on another server

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem last time. The old code that produce error still running in the queue. Try clear and restart queue.

```
$ php artisan clear-compiled
$ php artisan queue:restart
```

Comment: Hi @hafiz, I have tried your solution but no success. I just don't understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Supervisor to process my queue, and found i'd made changes to my code without restarting supervisor

I ran

```
sudo supervisorctl restart all
```

And it resolved all my issues

Answer (score 0):

this is most probably a serialization issue. use array syntax in your view:

use `$user['name']` instead of `$user->name`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, except I had no jobs in my application, only notifications. Notifications are ran through ShouldQueue and nothing indicates that you:

1. must restart queue
2. probably declare variable type
   `public User $user`
   `php artisan queue:restart`